# can't call class method with parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, class-method

I'm having trouble calling a class method from a View Controller. The class method takes a BOOL as input. Xcode allows me to call it without the parameter (which obviously crashes) but complains when I pass the parameter.

Here is the relevant code:

```
// RLI.h
@interface RLI : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
...
+(BOOL)askForLocationAccess;
end

// RLI.m
@implementation RLI
...
+(BOOL)askForLocationAccess:(BOOL)ask {
    ...
    return answer;
}
end

// CLOnboardingViewController.m
@implementation CLOnboardingViewController
...
-(IBAction)allowGPSAccess:(id)sender {
//    NSLog(@"%@", [sender currentTitle]);
    BOOL ask = [[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:gpsLabel];
    [RLI askForLocationAccess:YES]; // No known class method for selector 'askForLocationAccess:'
    [RLI askForLocationAccess]; // no complaint but crashes with "unrecognized selector sent to a class"
    [RLI askForLocationAccess:ask]; // what I intend to do

    ...
}
end
```

If more code is needed let me know, but this seems like it should be straightforward enough. I've looked through a bunch of "no known class method for selector" questions but most of them are either typos or calling an instance method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because your header class has the method without the parameter in it.
This is what you have in your .h file:

```
+(BOOL)askForLocationAccess;
```

Change it to:

```
+(BOOL)askForLocationAccess:(BOOL)ask;
```

Comment: I thought I had tried that but apparently not. I knew it had to be something simple! Thanks!